# Why can MA(q) (Moving Average Model with lag q) not predict q timesteps in the future

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, moving-average, moving-average-model

I understand that the equation for Moving Average model for lag q is -
$$
y_t = \mu + \epsilon_t + \theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}+ \theta_2\epsilon_{t-2}+\dots+ \theta_q\epsilon_{t-q}
$$

lets say we have training data of 100 timesteps and test data of 10 timesteps. and lag q = 2
I first evaluate the coefficients $\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\mu$
assuming $\epsilon_0=0\epsilon_{-1}=0$, then I evaluate $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_{100}$ using the above equation

$$\epsilon_1 = y_1-\mu-\theta_1\epsilon_0-\theta_2\epsilon_{-1}=y_1-\mu=f(y_1)$$

$$\epsilon_2 = y_2-\mu-\theta_1\epsilon_1-\theta_2\epsilon_{0}=y_1-\mu=f(y_2, y_1)$$

$$\vdots$$
so on and so forth to calculate $\epsilon_{100}$ since it will be $f(y_{100},y_{99},\dots,y_1)$

This means I could evaluate $y_{101}$, then $\epsilon_{101}$ using predicted $y_{101}$, then go on to $y_{102}, \epsilon_{102}$ and continue till $y_{110}$. This means that we can predict any number of values in the future and not be restricted to just $2$ values in the future i.e., lag. Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you use Latex for math formulas? And, what do you mean by "can not predict"? A model can predict anything even though it can be a very bad prediction.

Comment: An MA(2) model can absolutely predict. In R, try this: `predict(arima(rnorm(100),order=c(0,0,2)),n.ahead=10)`. Are you asking why the predictions are flat beyond two steps ahead? That is just a consequence of the fact that we don't know future innovations yet, or more precisely, that we use their expectation of zero.